# Running Tests in a separte JVM

Tags: java, junit, jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there a clean way to implement running `@Test`methods in each own separate jvm.
I got surefire setup to fork each TestClass but I need to run methods.

Each should start in it's own separate JVM. Ideally through an annotation so I could parametrise which tests can fork testcases and which one test methods

Comment: Just wondering: *why*? I have the vague feeling that you are investing your time on the wrong end. If your unit tests are as such that their level of "required isolation" requires *different* JVMs ... then chances are that your unit tests are not true unit tests. And then you should focus on that aspect: educating people how to write testable code and unit tests that can run in *one* JVM session together.

Comment: the answer is 'legacy code'. The application i'm testing is so old it and poorly written it doesn't even shutdown properly, i end up with OOME after running just few tests and we can't refactor old code. anyway it's too long to explain all the reasons

Comment: So you aren't talking about *unit* tests, but functional tests that happen to be run with JUnit?

Comment: @GhostCat, exactly. Each test method calls appStart and appShutDown. but as i've mentioned the shutDown doesn't actually kill all the threads.When new test method is called the appStart is called and JVM loads again all the objects with old ones still in heap.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve forked test execution using Maven's Surefire Plugin.

See the section about forked test execution in http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

This is the example from the page above illustrating how to create 3 forked executions:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <databaseSchema>MY_TEST_SCHEMA_${surefire.forkNumber}</databaseSchema>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <workingDirectory>FORK_DIRECTORY_${surefire.forkNumber}</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Nicely answering the question, although I think this is more of a band aid to fix symptoms caused by underlying design problems.

Comment: @gil.fernandes this will fork testcases not individual test methods

Comment: @testing_kate yes, you are right as far as I know. This applies to test cases, not single methods.